# How to get the records from Amazon Athena for past week only

Tags: aws

I am writing a query to get Amazon Athena records for the past one week only. Here is what I wrote so far:

```
WITH events AS (
  SELECT
    event.eventVersion,
    event.eventID,
    event.eventTime,
    event.eventName,
    event.eventType,
    event.eventSource,
    event.awsRegion,
    event.sourceIPAddress,
    event.userAgent,  
    event.userIdentity.type AS userType,
    event.userIdentity.arn AS userArn,
    event.userIdentity.principalId as userPrincipalId,
    event.userIdentity.accountId as userAccountId,
    event.userIdentity.userName as userName
  FROM cloudtrail.events
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (Records) AS r (event)
)
SELECT userName,sourceIPAddress,eventName,eventTime FROM events WHERE eventName='ConsoleLogin';
```

But I am not sure how to write it to extract records for the past 1 week only.

Comment: Please don't cross-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537086/how-to-get-results-from-athena-for-the-past-week

Comment: ohkie, i thought this more suited here . Still can you help @Philᵀᴹ

Comment: `eventTime` is of type `date`? Then surely adding `AND now() - eventTime < interval '1 week'` to the `WHERE` clause would do it?

Comment: @Colin'tHart  : Says SYNTAX_ERROR: line 20:106: '-' cannot be applied to timestamp with time zone, varchar

Comment: Sounds like `eventTime` is a varchar. Seriously bad design which you should fix.

Answer (score 9):

@Philᵀᴹ's answer is almost there. I just used it on my query and found the fix. I would have commented, but don't have enough points, so here's the answer.

You have to use `current_timestamp` and then convert it to iso8601 format. Like so:

```
WITH events AS (
  SELECT
    event.eventVersion,
    event.eventID,
    event.eventTime,
    event.eventName,
    event.eventType,
    event.eventSource,
    event.awsRegion,
    event.sourceIPAddress,
    event.userAgent,  
    event.userIdentity.type AS userType,
    event.userIdentity.arn AS userArn,
    event.userIdentity.principalId as userPrincipalId,
    event.userIdentity.accountId as userAccountId,
    event.userIdentity.userName as userName
  FROM cloudtrail.events
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (Records) AS r (event)
)
SELECT userName,sourceIPAddress,eventName,eventTime FROM events WHERE eventName='ConsoleLogin'
and eventTime > to_iso8601(current_timestamp - interval '7' day);
```

You can test the format you actually need by doing a test query like this:

```
SELECT to_iso8601(current_date - interval '7' day);
```

Returns: '2018-06-05'

```
SELECT to_iso8602(current_timestamp - interval '7' day);
```

Returns: '2018-06-05T19:25:21.331Z', which is the same format as event.eventTime, and that works.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Athena uses [Presto](https://prestodb.io), so you can use [any date functions that Presto provides](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html). You'll be wanting to use `current_date - interval '7' day`, or similar.

```
WITH events AS (
  SELECT
    event.eventVersion,
    event.eventID,
    event.eventTime,
    event.eventName,
    event.eventType,
    event.eventSource,
    event.awsRegion,
    event.sourceIPAddress,
    event.userAgent,  
    event.userIdentity.type AS userType,
    event.userIdentity.arn AS userArn,
    event.userIdentity.principalId as userPrincipalId,
    event.userIdentity.accountId as userAccountId,
    event.userIdentity.userName as userName
  FROM cloudtrail.events
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (Records) AS r (event)
)
SELECT userName,sourceIPAddress,eventName,eventTime FROM events WHERE eventName='ConsoleLogin'
and eventTime > current_date - interval '7' day;
```

Untested, I don't have access to a DB to test.

Comment: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 20:110: '>' cannot be applied to varchar, date

Comment: I can't help any further without a test environment, sorry. Will delete my answer

Comment: i am also confused.. what could be wrong :(

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Seems to me that error message would be a result of `eventTime` being a `varchar`...

Comment: @Colin'tHart I get that, but don't have Athena handy to test fixing it

Comment: FYI -- Presto SQL is now Trino